# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess', or one of its dependencies

Tags: vb.net

I am getting below error, Please help me, how can i resolve this issue.

Note: If I create window application then it is working without any error. However, when creating a web project, the following error is generated:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

I tried--

1.I change the apppool framework version to v4.0.30.319, intially it was v2.0.50727 but no benefit.
2.I tried to change target framework 4.0 to 2.0 and 3.5 but not successful to resolve the error.
3.I tried enabling 32 bit applications support in IIS.

**Web server configuration:**

```
Web server OS - Windows server 2008 R2 (64 bit)
Visual studio - 12
Language - Vb.net
Target framework - .Framework 4.0
Oracle client - 11.2.0.1.0 (64 bit)
Oracle.DataAccess DLL version - 11.2.0.1.0
```

**Database server configuration:**

```
Database server OS - Windows server 2008 R2(64 bit)
Database version is below:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.1.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

Comment: You have to install the Oracle Client on the web server.

Comment: Oracle client is installed so that I am able to run window application.   Oracle client - 11.2.0.1.0 (64 bit) is installed on web server.